# Digital signature and verification when the keys are in text files

Tags: ssh, signature

I generated a key-pair using ssh-keygen. They are in two text files, say "abc.txt" and "abc.txt.pub".
Now, I want to use the private key to sign a document.

I  did not find a way to do it with ssh, so I tried to use gpg:

```
gpg --sign --default-key=abc.txt features-devsite.txt
```

but got the following message:

```
gpg: no default secret key: secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
```

In this question: [How to sign files with Ubuntu command-line tools and my own keys?](https://askubuntu.com/q/679230/42073) there is a guide on generating keys with GPG, but I do not see how to sign when the key is in an existing text file.

Comment: I'm not sure that GPG keys and SSH keys are directly compatible - see for example [GPG & SSH Keys](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1402933)

Comment: Okay, so regardless of gpg, how can I sign my document with an ssh key?