# Can we sign the '.exe' (binary has ELF format)?

Tags: signature

We have PE format for Windows, which can be signed and verified using SignTool or verify --> RMB (Binary)-->Digital Signature.
Similarly, We have a binary (testFile.exe), which has the ELF format, which is the executable format used by Linux.
Can we sign the  '.exe' (binary has ELF format)? If yes, can you please share how we can sign and verify the signing of it?

Comment: version/distro of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.

@graham- Also context here is to understand for Linux Platform?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/679230/how-to-sign-files-with-ubuntu-command-line-tools-and-my-own-keys